# How to split dataframe or reorder dataframe by rows in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, split

I just want to clean the dataframe and analyse the dataframe. However, I got in trouble. I created a simple dataframe to illustrate it:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Resutls': ['IIL', 'pass','pass','IIH','pass','IIL','pass'], 'part':['None',1,2,'None',5,'None',4] }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

the result looks like:

```
    Resutls  part
0     IIL    None
1    pass      1
2    pass      2
3     IIH    None
4    pass      5
5     IIL    None
6    pass      4
```

There are some repeatable modules in the dataframe. I just want to reorder the dataframe by rows and drop the duplicated ones like:

```
    Resutls  part
0     IIL    None
1    pass      1
2    pass      2
6    pass      4 
3     IIH    None
4    pass      5
```

or just split the dataframe into several sub dataframes:

```
    Resutls  part
0     IIL    None
1    pass      1
2    pass      2
3    pass      4 

    Resutls  part
0     IIH    None
1    pass      5
```

This is just an easy example what I want to do. Actually I have a 4000-thousand rows dataframe, I tried to use reindex or df.iloc to do this. It is intuitive 
 for me but seems a little complicated to achieve. Is there any good way to do this? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need replace `pass` to `NaN`s and use forward filling, then sort by [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and reorder by `iloc`:

```
df = df.iloc[df['Resutls'].mask(df['Resutls'].eq('pass')).ffill().argsort()]
print (df)
  Resutls  part
3     IIH  None
4    pass     5
0     IIL  None
1    pass     1
2    pass     2
5     IIL  None
6    pass     4
```

Last remove repeating rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['Resutls'].duplicated() | (df['Resutls'] == 'pass')]
print (df)
  Resutls  part
3     IIH  None
4    pass     5
0     IIL  None
1    pass     1
2    pass     2
6    pass     4
```

If want each DataFrame separately:

```
df['g'] = df['Resutls'].mask(df['Resutls'].eq('pass')).ffill()
df = df[~df['Resutls'].duplicated() | (df['Resutls'] == 'pass')]
print (df)
  Resutls  part    g
0     IIL  None  IIL
1    pass     1  IIL
2    pass     2  IIL
3     IIH  None  IIH
4    pass     5  IIH
6    pass     4  IIL

dfs = {k:v.drop('g', axis=1) for k, v in df.groupby('g')}
#print (dfs)

print (dfs['IIH'])
  Resutls  part
3     IIH  None
4    pass     5

print (dfs['IIL'])
  Resutls  part
0     IIL  None
1    pass     1
2    pass     2
6    pass     4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. I will try that and I learned this.